# What are my chances of getting approved for a US B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, filipino-citizens

I’m a 23 y/o single woman from the Philippines. I recently graduated from college and will be taking a board exam this March 2018. Exam results (and further licensure application processes) will be released some time in June 2018. Now, my boyfriend (who came here just last year to see me) will be graduating from grad school this May, and his Mom has offered to sponsor my 2-3 week trip so I could meet his family and attend the graduation. I also have a newborn cousin that I’d visit if I get approved. I believe I have a fairly strong case, but of course I’m still doubtful.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention an important factor: I was issued a Schengen visa just last November 2017. I spent a month visiting 8 different Schengen countries from the middle of December to middle of January. I’ve also been issued a S. Korean visa and have traveled to other SE Asian countries.

Comment: It's hard to say based on the information you have provided. But your circumstances appear to be high-risk. Unless you have previous travel history in the USA, I would say your chances are bleak. However, the worst that can happen is your application will be refused and they will ask you to apply when your circumstances change.

Comment: If you plan to apply, collect evidence that you will return to your home country. While a letter of sponsorship and a good reason to travel may help to convince them that the purpose of your travel is a good one, you normally only get a visa if the visa officer is also convinced that you will return to your home country afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe I have a fairly strong case

Not at all. On the contrary, you seem to have significantly more ties to the US than to the Philippines.

Wait until you get a permanent, stable job, and have had it for at least 6 months. Then consider applying with substantial proof of your ties to the Philippines. Because the fact that you have an American boyfriend and a little cousin there, and that you are from the Philippines (not exactly a low-risk country), will make it harder for you to convince the embassy to issue the visa.

Comment: For reference, the B visa refusal rate for the Philippines in 2017 was just over 25% https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY17.pdf

Comment: @jcaron Well clearly Filipinos are no Somalis but the additional fact that OP comes across as a high-risk individual, again I would not chance it (as USD 160 is a lot to chuff down the toilet) until she gets a stable career.

Comment: Definitely wasn’t my intention to say that the refusal rate is low, just giving an additional data point. Not Afghanistan for sure, but also far from the rates observed for Western European countries.